# Unable to get a variable value in drools and use it to set in another field

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools

drl file :

```
rule "pendingMsgSizeModified"
when
$tibcoEMSObj : TibcoEMSData(deliveredMsgCnt.contains("MB") && pendingMsgSize \> 100)  
eval (!($tibcoEMSObj.typeOfAlert != null))
then
$tibcoEMSObj.setSendEmail(true);
$tibcoEMSObj.setTypeOfAlert($tibcoEMSobj.getTypeOfAlert()+"pendingMsgSize###");
update($tibcoEMSObj)
end
```

It gives error at this location : `$tibcoEMSobj.getTypeOfAlert()`

```
Error : \[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: org.drools.core.spi.KnowledgeHelper.$tibcoEMSobj()\]
\[Near : {... SObj.setTypeOfAlert($tibcoEMSobj.getTypeOfAlert()+ ....}\]
```

I am expecting to use the getter method to get it and concatenate the string to set in another variable and save/update it

Comment: is `typeOfAlert` a public field in TiboEMSData?

Comment: and what even are you trying to key off of in that eval? `typeOfAlert == null` ? that seems to be what `!(x != null)` cleans up to...

Comment: Also your error is indicating that `$tibcoEMSobj` has no method `getTypeOfAlert()`, which indeed it does not. The variable is after all `$tibcoEMSObj` and you've spelled it wrong. It's an undeclared variable and that's what the error is poorly attempting to inform you.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is all over the place. And without actually seeing your model, it's hard to tell what you're even trying to do.

But based on what you said:

> I am expecting to use the getter method to get it and concatenate the string to set in another variable and save/update it

And the code you did provide, I think *this* is what you're trying to do:

```
rule "pendingMsgSizeModified"
when
    $tibcoEMSObj : TibcoEMSData(
        deliveredMsgCnt.contains("MB"),
        pendingMsgSize > 100,
        $alertType: typeOfAlert != null
     )
then
    String newAlert = $alertType + "pendingMsgSize###";
    modify($tibcoEMSObj) {
        setSendEmail(true)
        setTypeOfAlert(newAlert)
    }
end
```

I presumed that your eval was either typo'd or just plain wrong since it was checking that the value was actually null. Don't use `eval` unless you have absolutely no other choice. (And I've never actually run into a situation where there was no other choice.)

I also presumed that the alert type will not change. I don't know what your `sendEmail` method does, or if it has side effects; if it does have side effects that change the typeOfAlert, then you'll of course need to call `getTypeOfAlert()` after calling setSendEmail.